# How to get speed and acceleration from trajectory data?

Tags: java, trajectory

I am using Java and netbeans as a IDE to develop a project. I have got some trajectory data by applying a spatial query. My question is, how can I get speed and acceleration for these trajectory data? Does java has useful library for me?
for more information: points has (x,y,z,t)
[image]